# VSTS won't publish *.resx and *.rldc files after successful build

Tags: asp.net, azure, continuous-integration, visual-studio-2017

I have a ASP.NET Web Application using MVC5 Razor. I am using VS2017 Team Explorer (Git) for versioning and on push am building my web application within Visual Studio Team Services. After build success I deploy to Microsoft Azure. Everything works as expected except that on Release my set-up and configuration won't publish the App_GlobalResources (containing my resource files for language) and CommonReports (containing my visualized reports from Microsoft.ReportViewer) folders and files.

**Folder content**

```
/App_GlobalResources/
     - Resource.resx
     - Resource.de.resx
/CommonReports/
     - CustomerRatingsReport.rdlc
```

**File properties**

- Resource.resx

[image: Resource.resx]

- Resource.de.resx

[image: Resource.de.resx]

- CustomerRatingsReport.rdlc

[image: CustomerRatingsReport.rdlc]

**Azure Release Definition**
[image: Azure-release-definition]

When I publish manually within Visual Studio 2017 (Right-click on file / folder, "Publish ", the files are successfully published to azure and the application works fine.

The files are available within my repository.

How can I automatically publish these files on successful build?

Comment: For RDLC try to change "Build Action" property to "Content".

Comment: Seemed to have done the trick. But I could remember that I had a problem with this configuration and hat to set it back to "Embedded Resource". Either way, thanks!